# Display last business day of every month in the database table. (Business day does not include Saturday, Sunday)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to display last business day (excludes Saturday, Sunday) of every month in the database table.

Comment: You really need to use a calendar table for this sort of thing. Just blindly saying the last day of the month and excluding only Saturday and Sunday is inadequate almost always. It doesn't take into account holidays.

Answer (score 0):

We use pgadmin, I'm guessing it's similar to SQL Server, here is a query we use:

```
bolReturn = true;

--Get the day of week
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM _start)
Into dayofweek;

--Sataurday
if dayofweek = 6 then
   bolReturn = false;
--Sunday
ELSIF dayofweek = 0 then
bolReturn = false;
end if;

--Check against office closing
select count(*) as start 
into intCount
from tables.officeclosed where closeddate = _start;

if intCount > 0 then
bolReturn = false;
end if;

return
```

`tables.officeclosed` would contain days you know you have off such as holidays and `_start` is the date you are passing in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create function dbo.LastBusinessDayOfMonth ( @Date date )
returns date as
begin
  declare @Result date;
  -- Find last day of the month
  set @Result = EOMONTH(@Date);
  -- If this date is Saturday or Sunday, 
  -- choose the preceding date
  while DATEDIFF(day,'0001-01-01',@Result)%7 >= 5
    set @Result = DATEADD(day,-1,@Result)
  return @Result;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly need more info, and as mentioned by Sean, you need to consider public holidays etc.

Following uses cross apply with "TOP 1" from subquery selecting 3 dates.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

select *
from
(
  SELECT Months.Idx, EOMONTH(datefromparts(year(getdate()), Months.idx, 1)) as EOMDate
  FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12) ) Months(Idx)
) Months
cross apply ( 
    select top 1 mldx.date AS LastBusinessDay
    from
    (
          select Months.EOMDate date
          union all select dateadd(day, -1, Months.EOMDate )
          union all select dateadd(day, -2, Months.EOMDate )
      ) mldx
    where datepart(weekday, mldx.date ) <= 5
    order by mldx.date desc
  ) lastBusinessDay
```